# Meaning of a Lincoln Quote

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Given below is a quote from Lincoln:

> No man who is resolved to make the most of himself can spare time for personal contention, still less can he afford to take the consequences, including the vitiation of his temper and the loss of self control, yield to larger things to which you show no more than equal rights, and yield to lesser ones though clearly your own

The overall sense of the paragraph is understood, but the meaning of individual parts of it is not fully clear.

- "yield to larger things to which you show no more than equal rights, and yield to lesser ones though clearly your own" as I understand is actually a next sentence and not stated as the consequence of personal contention. In that case, what is the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The source you got this quote from did not punctuate accurately, and added a "to". This isn't one sentence, but several. They originate in [a letter](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/l/lincoln/lincoln6/1:1116.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) from Lincoln to an army officer named [James M. Cutts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_M._Cutts), who had been charged with several offenses, including altercations with fellow officers:

> Quarrel not at all. No man resolved to make the most of himself, can spare time for personal contention. Still less can he afford to take all the consequences, including the vitiating of his temper, and the loss of self-control. Yield larger things to which you can show no more than equal right; and yield lesser ones, though clearly your own. Better give your path to a dog, than be bitten by him in contesting for the right. Even killing the dog would not cure the bite.

The sentence you're asking about actually says "Yield larger things" not "Yield *to* larger things."

Lincoln advises not getting into arguments over large things unless Cutts is more than equally right in his position, and not getting into arguments over small things at all.