# Meaning of a Lincoln Quote part2

Tags: meaning, paraphrasing, quotations

This separate thread from [my other question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335915/meaning-of-a-lincoln-quote) is made since moderator had asked to restrict one question per thread.

Given below is a quote from Lincoln:

> No man who is resolved to make the most of himself can spare time for personal contention, still less can he afford to take the consequences, including the vitiation of his temper and the loss of self control, yield to larger things to which you show no more than equal rights, and yield to lesser ones though clearly your own

It is mentioned that one of the consequence of personal contention is "vitiation of his temper". What does that phrase mean?

Comment: Have you looked up 'vitiation' and 'temper' in any dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in response to your other question, the quote you have provided is not accurately punctuated, but you have correctly identified the vitiation of temper and the loss of self-control as the consequences to which Lincoln refers. The original passage can be read [at this link](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/l/lincoln/lincoln6/1:1116.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext).

**Vitiate** here means something between [definitions 1 and 2 of Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vitiate): impair, or morally debase.

**Temper** here likely refers more broadly to a person's general disposition or state of mind ([definition 1d](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temper)) than specifically to  anger.

So the consequences of engaging in "personal contention" are a loss of self-control and an impairment or moral debasement of a person's disposition.